# Jquery UI sortable update single record

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a list like this:

```
<ul id="sortable">
        <li class="ui-state-default" id="31">
              list item
        </li>

        <li class="ui-state-default" id="32">  
               list item            
        </li>
</ul>
```

And in the backend (cakePHP) I have the following action:

```
public function ajaxUpdateOrder(){
    $this->autoRender = false;

    if(!empty($this->request->data)){
        $MeetingsTable = TableRegistry::get('Meetings');
        $meeting = $MeetingsTable->newEntity();

        $meeting->id = $this->request->data['id'];
        $meeting->priority = $this->request->data['priority'];

        $MeetingsTable->save($meeting);
    }
}
```

I need to be able to catch the `id` from `li` element and its current possition to be able to make a request that fits the backend function, but I just cannot figure it out from the docummentation.

Any help or guidance is much appreciated.

**EDIT**

As requested in the comments below:

I want to fire an AJAX request after one of the items changes positions. With the request I need to pass two variables for each item that has changed it's position, namely: id (from `<li id="">`) and possition (new position in the `ul`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`update`](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-update) callback to trigger an ajax request:

```
$("#sortable" ).sortable({
   update: function(e,ui){
     $.ajax({
       url:'/ajaxUpdateOrder', // url of the service
       data: {
         id: ui.item.attr('id'),
         position: ui.item.index()
       }
     });
   } 
});
```